# CollectionView image does not update after ImagePicker picks an image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a collectionView cell that has an image in it. When the user taps on the image, the image picker is brought up. However, when an image is selected, the image in the collectionView does not update. I used the exact same code in a regular UIViewController and it worked, so I'm assuming it's because this is in a UICollectionViewController.

Here is the code that should update the image:

```
func updateCollectionView(image: UIImage) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0)
    if let LoginCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? LoginCell {
        LoginCell.logoImageView.image = image
    }
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

Here is the delegate function:

```
weak var delegate: LoginControllerDelegate?

func updateCollectionView(image: UIImage) {
    delegate?.updateCollectionView(image: image)
}
```

Here is the picker function that ties the delegate and updateCollectionView functions together:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])  {
    print(info)
    picker.delegate = self
    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] {

        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage as? UIImage

    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage as? UIImage
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        updateCollectionView(image: selectedImageFromPicker!)
    }
}
```

Here are the collectionView methods, the LoginCell is where I am trying to bring up the picker:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return pages.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item == pages.count{
        let loginCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: loginCellId, for: indexPath) as! LoginCell
        loginCell.delegate = self
        return loginCell
    }

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PageCell

    let page = pages[indexPath.item]
    cell.page = page

    return cell
}
```

Here is the delegate method I have created in my protocol:

`protocol LoginControllerDelegate: class {
    func updateCollectionView(image: UIImage)`

Comment: Are you reloading data after picking image?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't do anything

Comment: How are you updating the `imageView` in the cell? all your do here is update `logoImageView`

Comment: What do you mean update the `imageView`? I updated the UICollectionView, but that did not do anything so I deleted it. How do you update an `imageView` specifically?

Comment: @chillin' Can you show the collectionView methods that will give us idea what is the issue

Comment: 1. `loginCell.delegate = self` what delegate methods does your cell have? 2. what viewController is becoming the delegate of your `LoginControllerDelegate`?

Comment: 1. Here are the methods my LoginCell has `class LoginCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate`. 2. The viewController that is the delegate of `LoginControllerDelegate` is the viewController where I initiate the collectionView

Comment: @chillin' You want set the image just for this loginCell right ?

Comment: @chillin' Try like my solution

Comment: @Nirav I feel like I have tried everything to solve this issue. Could I share my files with you and have you take a look at it?

Comment: @chillin' Ok, send me the project will looked into it

Comment: How should I send you the project? Google drive?

Comment: @Nirav How should I send you the project?

Comment: @chillin' Currently will not able to access drive are you having any location where you can upload project and give me link

Comment: @chillin' Can you sent your drive link of your project ?

Comment: @chillin' You haven't respond is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the end of your method.

```
if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker, let yourCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0)) as? CustomCell {
    yourCell.logoImageView.image = selectedImage
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0)])
}
```

This will get a reference of your cell, update its `logoImageView` and reload the item.

Comment: What should I replace yourIndexPath with?

Comment: `indexPath` of the cell you want to update. are you using [collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview)?

Comment: No, I'm not using that. Can I just do `collectionView.reloadData()` instead?

Comment: yes you can do that, but you need to update your data model so that `cellForItem` uses the correct image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145287/discussion-between-chillin-and-joze-ws).